expected LP_c_short instance instead of _ctypes.PyCStructType
In a software made by someone else I have this function:
Result = GetStatusDownloadFile(self.server,pState,progress)

which according to the description should returns the status and the current progress of the download of a file but when it is executed it says:
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: TypeError: expected LP_c_short instance instead of _ctypes.PyCStructType

In my understanding the error in in the pState. In a guide I've seen that it is defined as an enum
typedef enum {
Error                = -1,
Inactive                = 0,
Config                = 1,
ListenBootMode        = 2,
ClearPattern                = 3,
SetBank                = 4,
ListenBank                = 5,
EraseFlash                = 6,
ListenErased                = 7,
Load                = 8,
Loading                = 9,
Terminate                = 10,
Successful                = 11,

}

So I thought I should define it into a structure like
class pState(Structure):
_fields_ = [("Error", c_short), ("Inactive", c_short), ("Config", c_short),
            ("ListenBootMode", c_short), ("ClearPattern", c_short),("SetBank", c_short),
            ("ClearPattern", c_short),("ListenBank", c_short),("EraseFlash", c_short),("Load", c_short),
            ("Loading", c_short),("Terminate", c_short),("Successful", c_short)]

But I have no idea on how to "convert" it into an LP_c_short

[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve)). Add the code (C and Python), expected and actual outputs.

From the error message, the function is expecting the C-equivalent of short* for the second parameter and appears to be using it as an output parameter. Create a ctypes.c_short instance and pass it by reference to the function, then extract the value returned.  It will be an integer matching one of the enumeration values.
import ctypes as ct

ERROR = -1
INACTIVE = 0
CONFIG = 1
LISTENBOOTMODE = 2
CLEARPATTERN = 3
SETBANK = 4
LISTENBANK = 5
ERASEFLASH = 6
LISTENERASED = 7
LOAD = 8
LOADING = 9
TERMINATE = 10
SUCCESSFUL = 11

state = ct.c_short()
... # missing code defining GetStatusDownloadFile, self.server, and progress
result = GetStatusDownloadFile(self.server, ct.byref(state), progress)
if state.value == SUCCESSFUL:
    ...


I made an attempt with this and I printed the ct.byref(state) result obtaining this:
<cparam 'P' (0x03BCD130)>
can you explain me how to interpret this print?

@martinmistere It’s a more efficient way to pass pointer parameters than creating an actual pointer type. See byref.  It’s used to pass a pointer to a function. The display just indicates it is a pointer.

print(state.value) to see the updated value after the function call.
